# Not able to install nfs-server on Raspberry pi that have KURA running on

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mount, nfs, kura

I want to be able to mount my disk based on the local network (Synology) to my Raspberry Pi but I got the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi /home $ sudo mount -vvv -t nfs -o username=user,password=pwd 192.168.1.99:/volumes1/Machines_backup ~/backup
mount.nfs: timeout set for Fri Nov 27 09:01:46 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'username=user,password=pwd,vers=4,addr=192.168.1.99,clientaddr=192.168.1.48'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

probobly because the 'nfs-server' was not installed:

```
pi@raspberrypi /home $ systemctl status nfs-server.service
● nfs-server.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

so tried to installed but I got the following problem probably because some dependency between KURA and firewall, I stopped KURA service but still same problem:

```
pi@raspberrypi /home $ sudo apt-get install  nfs-server -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'nfs-kernel-server' instead of 'nfs-server'
nfs-kernel-server is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up nfs-kernel-server (1:1.2.8-9) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K02firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'firewall.tmp' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service kura and firewall.tmp if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service firewall.tmp at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service kura at depth 1
insserv: Stopping firewall.tmp depends on kura and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package nfs-kernel-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nfs-kernel-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What to do to be able to mount my disk?
Thanks in advance for your help!